Can't add reCaptcha to Mailchimp signup form
I am running Drupal 10.3.2, Mailchimp (Drupal module mailchimp 2.2.4) and reCaptcha (Drupal module 8.x-33).  The signup form works fine, and the reCaptcha works on all my forms EXCEPT for the Mailchimp signup form.  The signup form is in a block.  Using Chrome Inspect, I saw that the Form ID is mailchimp-signup-subscribe-block-get-my-free-newsletter-form, so I added that as the CAPTCHA point.  I also looked at the "Devel" option on the Mailchimp Configuration Signup Form and I see that originalID and id are both get_my_free_newsletter, so I used that for the machine-readable name in the Captcha point as well as the form id.  (I also see that "entitTypeId" is "mailchimp_signup" but I didn't do anything with that.)  I cannot get the reCaptcha form to show up on the signup form.  Can anyone help me?
